# PGFplots within Environ format mistake

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, environments

I try to write an environment for a simple barplot with **pgfplots** to reduce the needed markup.
For that I use the **environ** package.

For some reason tikz complains about a format mistake at the provided coordinates.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{barplot}{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
            xtick=data,
            ymax=40,
            ymajorgrids=true
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {
                \BODY
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{barplot}
(A, 10)(B, 20)(C, 30)
\end{barplot}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have any problems with the code. I have pgfplots v1.12 and TikZ v3.0.0. What is the complaint on your case?

Comment: @percusse Thanks for your reply. Indeed, my pgfplots version was v1.8. After I updated it, the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an older `pgfplots` wants to see an expanded coordinate list rather than a coordinate list in a macro, then it can be expanded with lots of `\expandafter` or the following way:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{barplot}{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
            xtick=data,
            ymax=40,
            ymajorgrids=true
          ]
            \edef\processme{%
              \noexpand\addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {
                \BODY
              };%
            }\processme
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% comment to remove unwanted space
}

\begin{document}

\begin{barplot}
(A, 10)(B, 20)(C, 30)
\end{barplot}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Better variant of `egreg`, which does not expand the cell entries:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{barplot}{%
     \def\process##1{%
       \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {##1};
     }%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
            xtick=data,
            ymax=40,
            ymajorgrids=true
          ]
            \expandafter\process\expandafter{\BODY}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{barplot}
(A, 10)(B, 20)(C, 30)
\end{barplot}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\BODY`, package `environ` also offers an interface with `\collect@body`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{barplot}{%
  \collect@body\process@barplot
}{}
\def\process@barplot#1{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
            xtick=data,
            ymax=40,
            ymajorgrids=true
          ]
            \addplot[ybar, fill=gray] coordinates {#1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{barplot}
(A, 10)(B, 20)(C, 30)
\end{barplot}

\end{document}
```

As percusse [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247590/pgfplots-within-environ-format-mistake#comment588882_247590), with `pgfplots` v1.12 and TikZ v3.0, the expansion tricks are not needed.

Comment: Shouldn't `\noexpand\BODY` be `\BODY`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, I'd do `\def\processme##1{\addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {##1}}` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\expandafter\processme\expandafter{\BODY};` where you do the `\edef`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, plain `\BODY`. The `\noexpand` was a left-over from a test.

Comment: @egreg Yes, `\process` is better, because this method does not expand the cell entries. Also I have added a variant with interface `\collect@body`.